# How to share message on facebook wall from my Android app?

Tags: android, android-facebook

I think, this is very simple problem. I have one button in my app. If i click it it executes one method. In this method i want to share "Hi this is xxx using xxxxx product" message on user's facebook wall. How can i do that? Is there any tutorials?

```
myMethod(){
//share on fb wall

}
```

Comment: ofcourse there is. on the official facebook site for example:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

Comment: Ok.. thank you. Any practical examples/tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

From [Sharing in Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) tutorial:

> Prerequisites
>
> Before you can share to Facebook from your app, or attempt to follow
>   any of the sharing tutorials, you will need:
>
> Your environment set up A Facebook app properly configured and linked
>   to your Android app, with SSO enabled The Facebook SDK added to your
>   project If you haven't done this and need help doing so, you can
>   follow our [getting started guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started).

Then essentially, have your `myMethod` call this:

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi.. i have downloaded facebook sdk. And i have imported it into my eclipse. Now it is unable to recognize " WebDialog " showing error.